# How can I change text color in java with using Enigma library?

Tags: java

So I have to use Enigma console in my project and interface is so complicatied so I have to use colors but I don't now how to use those for Enigma interface. There is the sample code:

```
import enigma.core.Enigma;
import enigma.event.TextMouseListener;

public enigma.console.Console cn = Enigma.getConsole("Mouse and Keyboard");
cn.getTextWindow().output(px,py,'P');
```

I couldn't do anything because I don't know. I searched the same problem in stackoverflow but this is one of a kind problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution :

```
import enigma.console.TextAttributes;
```

so this "TextAttributes" adds text colors like this:

```
public TextAttributes Pcolor=new TextAttributes(Color.RED);
```

this code adds red color when implement a console char or string, I mean:

```
cn.getTextWindow().output(px,py,'P',Pcolor);
```

like this and ta da, our char is ready and it's red!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with simple `system.out.println()`. But if you must use Enigma, the above solution you also provided works well.

Using these:
`public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";`

`public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";` // the color codes are the strings.

Which you can then use like this: `System.out.println(ANSI_BLACK + "your string" + ANSI_RESET);`

You MUST use ANSI_RESET at the end or it will apply the color to all print outputs.

Here are all the color codes:
`public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";`
`public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";`
`public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";`
`public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";`
`public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";`
`public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";`
`public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";`
`public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";`
`public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";`

Note: By the way, we are doing the same "Gravity" game project from the same university.
Best of luck to both of us :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).